# I can go from form4 to form5 but I can't do it the other way

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

This first code is to go to form5

```
private: System::Void btnSend_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             MessageBox::Show("Updated task was sent to project manager.");
             Form5^ f5 = gcnew Form5();
             f5->ShowDialog();
         }
```

But I thought it would be the same thing of I want to get back to form4 while I'm on form5

```
private: System::Void btnBack_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         this->Hide();
         Form4^ f4 = gcnew Form4();
         f4->ShowDialog();
     }
```

But I'm getting a lot of errors, Help me?

Comment: What errors, exactly?  How does Form4 differ from Form5?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "go back" (close Form5), then you just Need to Close the Form5 (this.Close()).